# Manual testing of mail server

Tags: manual-testing

I need to check mail server written with Erlang and CommuniGate Pro with black box method.

I already checked work of POP3/IMAP/SMTP protocol via telnet.

Also work of mail server via STARTTLS, SSL/TLS with the list of popular mail clients (Thunderbird, The Bat, MS Outlook and several others).

I can't check the web version because it doesn't done yet. There is only server interactions with clients. What also should I check here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you familiar with [37 Sources for Test Ideas](http://thetesteye.com/posters/TheTestEye_SourcesForTestIdeas.pdf)
 ?
being careful not to step on anybody's copyrights here are some examples-
- look for similar products, technologies or use cases either in your company or the general industry

- look for standards, de facto industry standards or just conventions
- think about the clients and how would they use the product, if you have real usage information it's even better
- previous version of this or similar products
- and plain common sense